# how to override the position of an onItemClick in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, button, custom-adapter

So I have a button, and this button switches the cell of a listview with the cell above, and vise versa for ANOTHER button which is for down (this one is for up... It doesn't matter which, I just decided to talk about this one). The whole button and list view thing is working, but my problem is when I press the up button, and then decide to press it again, it just acts as a down button. The reason for this is because it's still stuck on the same item/position of the list view, and I need to figure out a way to Override the position of the onItemClick in the code??

```

upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
                            @Override

                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                //upButton onClick

                                Integer myTeam = position; //7 -159

                                Integer otherTeam = position - 1; //6 - 1678

                                Map<Integer, String> onClickMap = sortByValue(Constants.picklistMap);

                                String extraValue;

                                Log.e("myposition", myTeam.toString());

                                Log.e("otherposition", otherTeam.toString());

                                extraValue = onClickMap.get(myTeam); //159

                                String team = onClickMap.get(otherTeam);

                                Constants.picklistMap.put(myTeam, onClickMap.get(otherTeam));

                                Constants.picklistMap.put(otherTeam, extraValue); //6

                                Log.e("Position: ",Constants.picklistMap.get(position));

                                Log.e("Position - 1: ",Constants.picklistMap.get(position - 1));

                                if(myTeam != 0) {

                                    dref.child("picklist").child(myTeam.toString()).setValue(Integer.parseInt(Constants.picklistMap.get(myTeam)));
                                    dref.child("picklist").child(otherTeam.toString()).setValue(Integer.parseInt(Constants.picklistMap.get(otherTeam)));


                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nice try. 
    If you try it again, the app is going to crash as punishment ... (:",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                            }

                        });
```

```

By overriding the position, I just mean how 
`position =+ 1`
would make position = position + 1 in python, and I want to do the same thing in Java. The problem is I know that can't be done using the snippet of code I just used to increment the value of position!

Please help!

The reason I can't use `position = position + 1` is because on the onItemClick, int position is defined, and then the onClick is created for the buttons, so I need position to be final for me to use it in the onClick, and if I got rid of final, i wouldn't be able to use it in the onClick as it can't be accessed from within an inner class when it's not final

Comment: To pass position to onClick without making it final, you may try:- 1. Inside onClick(), add: int position = (int)v.getTag(); 2. Inside getView() before it return view, add: upButton.setTag(position); Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Define which position you want to change, and use this method to update position. You can use this method in onClickListener. This should work.

```
    private int position = 0;

    private void up(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
            if (position < 1 || position >= arr.size()) return;
            int temp = arr.get(position - 1);
            arr.set(position - 1, arr.get(position));
            arr.set(position, temp);
            position --;
        }
```